# Python Django Best Practice for request.user in Class Based Views and Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am using class based views and have always the same problem without an elegant solution.
My querysets should only show the ones that are owned of the request user.

### Code

view:

```python
class MyListView(ListView):
    model = MyModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.owned_by_user(self.user)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.user = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = request.user

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

model:

```python
class MyModelQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def owned_by_user(self, user):
        return self.filter(user_field=user)


class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModelQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def owned_by_user(self, user):
        return self.get_queryset().owned_by_user(user)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    user_field = ...

    objects = ProductRequestManager()
```

### Best practice 1:

I think I have to overwrite dispatch to add the request.user.
My IDE notes "Instance attribute user defined outside of **init**. In order to prevent this I also need to overwrite **init**(). How can I achieve this with less code?

### Best practice 2:

Is there another way to get querysets belonging to the current user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just filter the queryset with `self.request.user`. Note that the `setup()` method will assign values to `self.request`, `self.args`, and `self.kwargs`:

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    model = MyModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.owned_by_user(self.request.user)
```

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why I haven't checked self.request correctly.

Comment: The `UserPassesTestMixin` is a good tip. I have the `self.request.user` there. But if I would like to check if the user is in the field MyModel.user I seem to have no chance. `self.object` is not available here:

`def test_func(self):
    return self.request.user == self.object.user # AttributeError: has no attribute 'object'`

Comment: @moritz_h: no that is correct, since assigning `self.object` is done after the dispatch, and the test is done as part of the `dispatch`. Normally the test means you check something about the user itself (for example if it is an admin), not about the object and how it relates to the user. You can filter that in `get_queryset`, or for a `SingleObjectMixin` view, in `get_object`.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, i am fine with the permission check in overwriting get_object.